# Issues with indentation in python Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

I'm working on the documentation for the [pytket python package](https://github.com/CQCL/tket).

I have noticed some indentation issues in our API docuentation which looks bad in the built html pages. It may also be relevant that the module in question is python wrapped around some C++.

[image]

The source rst for the page is as follows.

```
.. currentmodule:: pytket._tket.circuit.OpType
.. autoclass:: pytket._tket.circuit.OpType
    :members:
```

The source file can be found [here](https://github.com/CQCL/tket/blob/develop/pytket/docs/optype.rst)

Note that "Members:" appears in the built html which should not happen and did not happen before. Every instance I've found of this relates to python bindings around enums defined in C++. Could this be the issue?

I suspect the change comes from upgrading a package but I can't seem to track down the exact change.

Am I using some deprecated syntax here? The same issue appears elsewhere in our docs [here](https://cqcl.github.io/tket/pytket/api/partition.html) for example.

I am using the following versions of sphinx and associated packages

```
sphinx==6.1.0
sphinx_autodoc_annotation==1.0post1
sphinx-book-theme==1.0.1
enum-tools[sphinx]==0.1.0
```

I have tried altering the syntax in the source but the issue persists.

Edit: following discussion in the comments I tried using a different theme and using sphinx-auto-doc-typehints instead of the old sphinx-autodoc-annotation and the issue persists.

Comment: A stab in the dark: the sphinx-autodoc-annotation extension is rather old (last release was in 2016;   https://pypi.org/project/sphinx-autodoc-annotation/). Perhaps it does not play well with newer versions of Sphinx.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this was a good suggestion. I think I've been able to  rule this out now as I have built the docs in an environment without sphinx-autodoc-annotation installed and the issue persists.

Comment: OK. Have you tried a different theme?

Comment: I tried building with the sphinx rtd theme instead and the `Members:` word still appears in the html. The indentation issue isn't quite as noticeable although its still there.